# MATLAB xcorr different size of signals

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3

I am trying to make a project like shazam but i stucked. I wanna load an template signals(which is songs) and  when i load some part of a song it should be compare template signals and say this is your song.I am thought using xcorr function but when i use it matlab gives error like vectors size should be same.So obviously my template songs and the signal which i try to compare with them is not same size.So what should i do? Should i use some other fuction then xcorr or what can i do differently?
and this is my code block:

```
[y,fs] = audioread('sound.wav');
[y2,fs2] = audioread('sound4.mp3');

y = y(:,1);
y2 = y2(:,1);
dt = 1/fs;
t = 0:dt:(length(y)*dt)-dt;
figure(1);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,y); xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude');         %time domain
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(psd(spectrum.periodogram,y,'Fs',fs,'NFFT',length(y)));%frequency domain

figure(2);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,y2); xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude');         %time domain
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(psd(spectrum.periodogram,y2,'Fs',fs,'NFFT',length(y2)));%frequency domain

[C1,lag1] = xcorr(y,y2);
C1_new = C1./max(abs(C1(:)));

figure(3);
ax(1) = subplot(211);
plot(lag1/fs,C1_new,'k');
ylabel('Normalized Amplitude');
grid on;
title('cross corre')
xlabel('time (second)');
```

Comment: If you are getting an error similar to `Error using coder.internal.assert (line 33)
When B is a vector, A must be a vector.` It suggest that the two suond files have different numbers of channels. For instance `'sound.wav'` may be stereo while `'sound4.mp3'` is mono

Answer (score 2):

Quickly mocking up a `y` and `y2` signal of different lengths shows that this is not an error with `xcorr`. Rather, the error you receive is `Error using plot Vectors must be the same length.` Which stems from here `plot(t,y2);`

You cannot use `t` to plot against `y2` if `y2` has a different length to `y`

#### Suggestion

Create a second `t` vector, `t2`, and make it the length of `y2`

```
[y,fs] = audioread('sound.wav');
[y2,fs2] = audioread('sound4.mp3');

y = y(:,1);
y2 = y2(:,1);
dt = 1/fs;
t = 0:dt:(length(y)*dt)-dt;
t2 = 0:dt:(length(y2)*dt)-dt;

figure(1);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,y); xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude');         %time domain
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(psd(spectrum.periodogram,y,'Fs',fs,'NFFT',length(y)));%frequency domain

figure(2);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t2,y2); xlabel('Seconds'); ylabel('Amplitude');         %time domain
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(psd(spectrum.periodogram,y2,'Fs',fs,'NFFT',length(y2)));%frequency domain

[C1,lag1] = xcorr(y,y2);
C1_new = C1./max(abs(C1(:)));

figure(3);
ax(1) = subplot(211);
plot(lag1/fs,C1_new,'k');
ylabel('Normalized Amplitude');
grid on;
title('cross corre')
xlabel('time (second)');
```